# What is the species of this green and orange spider?

Tags: bug-identification, spider

I was recently outside in my backyard in a sandy area, and I found this spider. I live in Texas, and have never seen anything like it. I have done some research, and found nothing. It might be hard to see in the picture but this is a green & orange spider. Does anybody know what it is?

[image: Green & Orange Spider]

Answer (score 10):

I am fairly sure that you’ve found a [Crab Spider](https://entomology.tamu.edu/studylist_all/crab-spiders/)  based on the entry in [this website](https://thebugmaster.com/spiders-in-austin-texas/), which looks nearly exactly like your photo.

[image: Image if a green spider nearly identical to the one posted by the asker; photo from https://thebugmaster.com/]

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it looks like a crab spider- they are super cool! The tend to hide on flowers (and can change color to match the flower) to pounce and prey upon visiting pollinators like bees, flies, and butterflies. They don't build webs at all, they just use those long front legs to grab unsuspecting visitors. Check out open flowers in your yard. They are part of a very large family of spiders (Thomisidae) and there is more info on [Bug Guide](https://bugguide.net/node/view/1957) (a great entomology website) about identification.
I have seen them sitting on or under flowers with those front legs up and it is unnerving...of course you can check this out on  on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vots57T-mQA), not for the faint-hearted...